# Getting CHIP_ID from BMI_270 using SPI Interface from Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, spi, gyroscope, imu

Fundamentally I'm trying to extract Accel and Gyro values from the sensor using SPI interface. However there are limited support for BMI270 available online, so I'm now reading the values using registers mapping from the datasheet. I'm first trying to get the chip ID (which should be 0x24 according to data sheet) but so far I have been unsuccessful in it. I'm attaching my code so you can get an idea.

```
#include <SPI.h>

// Chip Select Pin for Xiao ESP32-C3
const int CS = A1;

// Command to read chip ID
const byte CMD_READ_CHIP_ID = 0x80 | 0x00;

// // Chip Select Pin
// const int CS = 10;

// Command to read from an address
const byte CMD_READ = 0x80;

// Command to write to a register
const byte CMD_WRITE = 0x00;
const byte CMD_RESET = 0xB6;

// Register address to enable SPI interface
const byte REG_SPI_INTERFACE = 0x70;
const byte VAL_SPI_INTERFACE = 0x01;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // SPI.begin();
  // SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST);
  // SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16);  // Set SPI clock frequency to 1 MHz
  // SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);            // Set SPI mode to 3 (CPOL=1, CPHA=1)

  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);

   // Enable SPI interface
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  SPI.transfer(CMD_WRITE);
  // SPI.transfer(CMD_RESET);
  SPI.transfer(REG_SPI_INTERFACE);
  SPI.transfer(VAL_SPI_INTERFACE);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
   digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  SPI.transfer(CMD_READ | CMD_READ_CHIP_ID);
  byte chipID = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);

  Serial.print("Chip ID: 0x");
  Serial.println(chipID, HEX);

  delay(1000);
}
```

The expected result should be 0x24 but I'm getting 0x0 as a result. I've checked my connection. I'm even attaching the pin mapping from Bosch BMI270 to Xiao ESP32-C3 board.

```
BOSCH BMI-270 --- XIAO ESP32-C3
GND           --- GND
3.3V          --- 3V3
CS            --- A0
SCL           --- SCL
SDA           --- MOSI
SDO           --- MISO
```

I've double-checked the connections and they're all ok.

Edit: Code has been added to include SPI.beginTransaction() and SPI.endTransaction().

Comment: BMI 270 reset is much more involved that a simple reset command, it described in the section 4.4 of BMI 270 datasheet. There is a [BMI270 Sensor API](https://github.com/boschsensortec/BMI270-Sensor-API) library provided by Bosch that you can use (it is in c but already wrap with c++ guard).

Comment: BTW, `SPI.setBitOrder()`, `SPI.setClockDivider()` and `SPI.setDataMode()` methods are deprecated since 2014! You should use the [SPISettings](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/spi/spisettings/) object to configure your SPI instance, and use transactional API (i.e. `SPI.beginTransaction()` and `SPI.endTransaction()`) for each data transaction.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. For the BMI270 Sensor API, it is only designed for c code. I didn't understand the c++ guard though. There's one example code in the API just to retrieve accel data. How can I use that example code in Arduino? Or do I have to make a separate code base for that, so it can working in the IDE?

Comment: @hcheung I have tried the SPI.beginTransaction() and SPI.endTransaction() and it didn't work for me and I still wasn't able to get the chipID from the device in anyway. I have updated the above code so you can see how it is now!